# Creating Spring rest api web-services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am developing a restful web-service using java and spring-Boot.

I'm asking this question because i'm new to java and tried to study the web-services i can only find how we can create locally  but  i want to i have to use a third party API.

I will be the data from  front-end and then i  have to send it to this URL to verify and save the response.

This is Company UI file

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


public class CompanyUI implements Serializable{

     @NotNull(message = "error.field.null")
     @Size(min = 4, max = 40, message = "error.field.size")
     private String key;

     @NotNull(message = "error.field.null")
     private Integer id;

     @NotNull(message = "error.field.null")
     private String name;

     @NotNull(message = "error.field.null")
     private boolean abc;

    public String getkey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setkey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isabc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setKyc(boolean abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I'm asking this question*  - actually you are not asking a question

Comment: Since you are just starting out, may I suggest a much simpler project you can use to make web service called [`sparkJava`](http://sparkjava.com/)

Comment: No i have to use spring @Ab Sin

Comment: I don't know how i can dynamically post URL in the code

Comment: where is your `@Controller`? Refer [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start)

Comment: You can find the example to create rest ws in Spring doc (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: http://search.ofac-api.com/api/v1?name=John Smith&minScore=75&data=xml&apiKey=demo_key this is the website for api i have to consume this @Ab Sin

Answer (score 0):

You should study MVC design pattern and apply using spring framework . For demo https://www.java4s.com/spring-mvc/